# grammaticality of 'for what to blame them is a bit unfair'

Tags: word-order, relative-pronouns, infinitive-vs-gerund, run-on-sentences

> The subordinates have had to take these steps in accordance with instructions of the top management of the company, for what to blame them is a bit unfair.

I am considering the possibility of using the construction 'for what to blame them is a bit unfair'. What do you think about grammaticality of this construction?

The meaning of this phrase is that the subordinates have been forced to take these steps because of internal rules defined by the senior managers of the company. It is unfair to shift the blame for these steps on to the subordinates.

Comment: other considerations aside... 'instructions from' not 'of'

Comment: Perhaps try, "[...], and to blame them for that is a bit unfair." *A bit unfair* being at the end of the sentence lends itself to emphasis on the unfairness. Arguably, this might make *them* ambiguous (though not very much, in my opinion). If you have such a feeling, you can replace *them* with *the subordinates*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt I had to change your word order a bit - or split your sentence into two main clauses:

> The subordinates have had to take these steps in accordance with instructions of the top management of the company, for which it is a bit unfair to blame them.

The word order "for what to blame them is a bit unfair" , slightly better "for which to blame them is a bit unfair" makes the sub clause look like a second main clause, not a relative subordinate as you seem to intend it.

You could write

> The subordinates have had to take these steps in accordance with instructions of the top management of the company. It is a bit unfair to blame them for that.

or

> The subordinates have had to take these steps in accordance with instructions of the top management of the company and it is a bit unfair to blame them for that.

Comment: Thanks. However, I meant to form one sentence composed of dependent parts.

Comment: @Humbulani I thought so, that is why I started with that :)

Comment: @ oerkelens Initially, my wording looked like the relative clause in your post. But then I 've come to the conclusion that it is not completely correct because the words "for which" belong to the whole phrase 'it is a bit unfair to blame them' not to the separate phrase "to blame them".  Maybe it is absolutely correct. I don't know.

Comment: I believe @oerkelens first answer is what you're looking for. It could be reworded as 'for which blaming them is a bit unfair', but moving *blame* to the start of the clause doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: @ Alan Third explain please what you mean by moving 'blame' to the start? Do you mean it is ok, when the infinitive of 'blame' is at the start of the dependent sentence? 

Using 'for which it is unfair', we get the other meaning, i.e. 

it is unfair to blame them because of the fact that they obeyed the orders of top-management. 

But I want to say that it is unfair to blame them for the steps they took. 

Correct me if I am mistaken about that.

Comment: I want to use the construction 'to blame somebody for something'.

Comment: The wording 'for which blaming them is a bit unfair' does not explain for what we should not blame them. It follows from this wording that blaming them is unfair for the reasons which are specified in the first part.

Comment: @Humbulani Having the second part as 'for which blaming them is a bit unfair' has exactly the same meaning as 'for which it is a bit unfair to blame them.' I just feel the former is clearer. If you need to use 'to blame X for Y' you may have to go with something like: 'and to blame them for that is unfair.' I'm unsure I understand what you are asking, every example given in every answer so far has the meaning you describe in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *what* as a relative pronoun in this way. *What* has the idea of 'the things that/which', as in *I like what you say*. One possibility for a relative construction for your sentence is:

*The subordinates have had to take these steps in accordance with instructions of the top management of the company,  to blame them for which is a bit unfair.*

The antecedent of 'which' is the whole main clause.

Comment: Um… Are you sure that it is possible to say this way ?        'to blame them for which is a bit unfair'. I don't like that at all :( I think there is something wrong with this phrase you've written.

Comment: What about the construction like '..., which is not the actions for which they are to blame.' ?

Comment: @Humbalani. I am sure 'to blame them for which is a bit unfair' is possible. I don't particularly like it myself, but there is nothing grammatically wrong with it. I would probably to do as oerkelens suggested - make a separate sentence of the relative clause.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Do you think my other construction ('actions') is not acceptable?

Comment: Your 'actions' sentence has a different meaning. It's saying they are to blame for something but not for following instructions. Your other sentence seems to be saying simply that it's unfair to blame them for following instructions.

Answer (score 0):

> The subordinates have had to take these steps in accordance with
>   instructions of the top management of the company, for which it is a
>   bit unfair to blame them.

**The subordinates have taken these steps in accordance with instructions from top management, and to blame them (for the consequences of these actions) is unfair.**

Either you have an opinion or you don't. "a bit unfair" is spineless.